# else condition not doing anything

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Trying to verify a hashed password which works fine if the entered password is true but if it isn't, then nothing happens.
which means anything written after 'else' doesn't work.
the code is something like this:

```
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        while ($row = $x->fetch_assoc()) {
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            ?>
            <div class="right">You are logged in!</div>
            <script>
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = "admin/adminpanel.php";
                }, 2000);
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    } else {
        echo "Wrong"; //Here I tried both echoing something or using html but none of them worked
        ?>
        <div class="wrong">Username or password is invalid</div>
        <?php
    }
```

**UPDATE** 
This is the full code if it's needed:
PHP:

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
    $x = $conn->query($q);
    $hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        while ($row = $x->fetch_assoc()) {
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            ?>
            <div class="right">You are logged in!</div>
            <script>
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = "admin/adminpanel.php";
                }, 2000);
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }  {
        ?>
        <div class="wrong">Username or Password is invalid</div>
        <?php
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <input name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" maxlength="20">
            <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20">
            <input class="loginbutton" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
```

Comment: Try to do a `var_dump(password_verify($password, $hash))` above your `if` statement to make sure that the if statement is actually failing. There is nothing wrong with the `if-else` in PHP. I can guarantee you that much.

Comment: if/else works 100%. It's not the else condition doing anything, you are definitely never reaching the password_verify part in the first place. Also, why cabbage code?

Comment: `code is something like this` Please post the actual code, not something "like" it. Your actual code may have bugs that aren't present in the code you post. Or even better, reproduce the problem in a minimal program we can run.

Comment: Most probably in your case `password_verify($password, $hash)` is true, but `$x->fetch_assoc()` is false.

Comment: @DirkScholten that actually causes a syntax error in the result page.

Comment: @Mjh cab you explain to me what is a cabbage code as I have absolutely no idea what it is ...

Comment: Well you have to actually put a `;` behind the `var_dump()` ofc :)

Comment: @Jackpotato - you do, it's unreadable piece of code with no identation which is very difficult to read and spot where one section starts or the other one ends. It's exactly like the cabbage you asked help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your code tracks fine for successful scenario. Which mean that you have `password_verify($password, $hash) === true` and `while ($row = $x->fetch_assoc()) {` equals true one time.

But for the scenario when second condition failed `$x->fetch_assoc() === false` you do nothing. And php goes after your `if ... else ...` statement.

To avoid this I suggest to remove your `else` line. That will change the code flow to go right after `if { ... }` when `while` never happened.

```
}
// else {
    echo "Wrong"; //Here I tried both echoing something or using html but none of them worked
    ?>
    <div class="wrong">Username or password is invalid</div>
    <?php
//}
```

Or probably you can remove your `while` loop. I don't see you are using `$row` anywhere.

```
 //while ($row = $x->fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        ?>
        <div class="right">You are logged in!</div>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = "admin/adminpanel.php";
            }, 2000);
        </script>
        <?php
    //}
```

**UPDATE** Your code should look more like 
   (I assumethat:
      - you are using `mysqli` 
      - username is unique across that table
      - column `password` stores hashes of user passwords
   )

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM users WHERE username= ?";
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $hash);
    if ($stmt->fetch()) {
       if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            ?>
            <div class="right">You are logged in!</div>
            <script>
                setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location.href = "admin/adminpanel.php";
                }, 2000);
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }  

    ?>
    <div class="wrong">Username or Password is invalid</div>
    <?php    
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but can you actually explain why I shouldn't use else here, (I'm a beginner)

Comment: I'm confused. Why remove the else? It should work just fine.

Comment: @Alex When I remove the while loop it won't verify the password, I mean anything you enter in the password input will be accepted as the correct password but the first solution is working.

Comment: @Jackpotato but what is `$hash` then? logically that is your hash stored in database and fetched somewhere previously. Isn't it?

Comment: @jack that means you're not actually checking the password at all. You have a bug of some kind in the code that retrieves/computes $password and $hash.

Comment: @Alex $hash is the hashed password which the user enters in the input, which now I think is completely wrong.

Comment: @Alex can you tell me what should I define `$hash` instead of `$hash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

Comment: You should use this $hash variable somewhere where you set up your DB query. Since I see `$x->fetch_assoc()` I expect that query was built somewhere up there. show me that fragment you just need to add some `WHERE` clause to that query

Comment: @Alex I know it's probably me doing something wrong but using the exact updated code you wrote now it won't redirect EVEN if you enter the correct username and password.

Comment: Did you read my assumptions? Do you have hashes stored in `password` column? Do you have unique user name? Do `var_dump($name); var_dump($hash);` next to `if ($stmt->fetch()) {`. what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

If I simplify what you have, and remove the mysqli_escape call - in essence this is what you have left:

```
<?php
if (
    password_verify(
        $_POST['password'],
        password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)
    )
) {
    echo 'Verified';
} else {
    echo 'Not verified.';
}
```

Now the above condition should always be satisfied (look closely), and display 'Verified'.

The logic is flawed in the above code.

To fix: you want to retrieve the hash of your previously saved password from the database, and then verify that (NOT the hash of the password you've just submitted/posted).

Above demonstration of logically flawed approach:
https://3v4l.org/C88H2